# Hide only bottom shadow of a Div using CSS

Tags: css

I want to show the box shadow on every side except bottom.

Here is the css I'm using.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 12px 4px #ddd;
```

How to remove bottom shadow from it?

Comment: box-shadow: 0 -Xpx 12px 4px #ddd; (second number/value -> X should be negative)

Comment: But it's making large shadow on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the dimensions of the shadow across one axis only (i.e you can't reduce just the height of the shadow). One trick is to add the shadow to a *pseudo element* and reduce the height of that element.

```css
.shadow {
  margin:20px;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  }
/* Pseudo element for adding shadow */
.shadow:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 4px #999;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the negative value to push it off the edge.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 12px 4px #888888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use more than 1 shadow:

```css
body {
  box-shadow: 
    -12px -10px 12px -4px /* negative value here decrease the size */#ddd, 
    12px -10px 12px -4px #ddd, 
    inset 0 -3px lime /* demo , show bottom */;
  padding:4em 8em;
  background:gray;
}

/* demo purpose */
html {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
}
```

it can draw [things like this](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKdJOE)